# mtom serving word doc

Tags: web-services, java-metro-framework, mtom

has anyone been able to serve a word doc using metro (webservices) as a mtom stream? Does anyone have example, or know where there is example code please for client and server?

Answer (score 3):

The [Large Attachments](https://metro.dev.java.net/guide/Large_Attachments.html) and [Binary Attachments (MTOM)](https://metro.dev.java.net/guide/Binary_Attachments__MTOM_.html) examples might help.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why folks at sun  write  half-baked stuff !

tried giving a simple sample code. Hope this helps

[JAX-WS MTOM Sample Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113656/jax-ws-mtom-sample-code-service-client-need-simple-one)