# Transfer binary and text data to Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, soap, glassfish, transport-stream

I need to transfer a large amount of data like video or audio from java based client (stand alone app or Android) to Glassfish 3.1.2 application server. The stream should contain text and binary data. I am thinking of a SOAP message containing the data in itself like this:

```
  <song>
      <title>Some name</title>
      <data dt:dt="binary.base64">84592gv8Z53815Zb82bA68g</data>
  </song>
```

... and at server side - Web Service to process the data. Is this the right approach to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go for the web service approach, I would recommend to use MTOM (Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism
From) to transfer large payload. See [How does MTOM work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619435/how-does-mtom-work-sample-code).

Comment: This looks nice having the data on bottom of the XML. I have to test this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't implement it by myself, instead use an existing framework for it.

Check out [Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/). I haven't used it by myself, but [Adam Bien](http://adam-bien.com/) keeps telling in his workshops that one should consider that for fast transfer of binary data.